# How to set javascript on child page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have two pages, a master page and child page. How can I set javascript on child page?

I want implement textchange function on child page using javascript.

Comment: Did you try including a `<script>` block in your child page?

Comment: Do you have 2 HTML pages (parent and child is inside IFrame of the first), or 2 HTML pages rendered one after another, or Master page/content ASPX file (render single HTML page)?

Answer (score 2):

Master Page :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server">       
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Child page :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="ContentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="**ContentPlaceHolderHead**" runat="server" >
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    // You can write a javascript code HERE...
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="ContentMain" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderMain" runat="server" >
    <!-- Content -->
</asp:Content>
```

In other way, you can add a javascript file in the code-behind file of child page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            HtmlGenericControl somejs = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            somejs.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            somejs.Attributes.Add("src", ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/js/something.js"));
            this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(somejs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add scrip inside a contentplaceholder and make sure you set the master page file of your child page eg: MasterPageFile="~/Mymaster.Master".

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

      //Your Script HERE
</script>


//YOUR HTML TAG HERE

</Content>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could user [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)t in your child page.